# Is there an algorithm to define a recursive function such that consecutive terms approach any arbitrary constant?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci sequence is defined by the recursive function, $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$. Consecutive terms in this sequence approach the constant, $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Is there an algorithm that produces recursive functions such that $f(n)/f(n-1)$ approaches any arbitrary algebraic constant?

Comment: Well, for any  number $\alpha$, algebraic or not, the sequence $f(n)=(\alpha+f(n-1))/2$ will converge to $\alpha$. You need to restrict the allowed types of recursive equations to make this question interesting. Something like, "Do there exist rational coefficents $a_1,\dots,a_d$ such that when $f(n)=a_1f(n-1)+\dots+a_df(n-d)$, then $\lim f(n)/f(n-1)=\alpha$?" You could also allow $a_1,\dots,a_d$ to be functions of $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is real algebraic and a root of the polynomial with rational  coefficients
$$p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$$
**and** we have $|\beta|<\alpha$ for all other (real or complex) roots $\beta$ of $p$,
then for a sequence defined by the recursion
$$x_{k}=-a_{n-1}x_{k-1}-\cdots-a_1x_{k-n+1}-a_0x_{k-n}$$
(and almost any choice of initial values), the quotients $\frac {x_{k+1}}{x_k}$ will converge to €$\alpha$.

For algebraic numbers that are not maximal in the above sense, you are out of luck.